# webpack set output path for js/css

Tags: webpack

In default webpack setting, the output js/css is under the root path, something like

```
    <link href=/css/app.ff6d5467.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.e6bc587c.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/js/app.a9f1ae4f.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.7cfe59d2.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.e6bc587c.css rel=stylesheet>
    <link href=/css/app.ff6d5467.css rel=stylesheet>
```

However, when I deploy my service, it's under a sub path of the host, something like http://all-services.com/myservice, where there is a nginx proxy routing all traffic under `/myservice` to my service, so these js/css will end up with 404 error because they're trying to access resource under http://all-service.com/js and http://all-service.com/css.

I want to change the path of these js/css when webpack build, change to `/myservice/js` and `/myservice/css` for example, how should I config this in webpack?

Comment: Hi Ziqi, do you only need js/css or all of your bundled files to be served at */myservice/*?

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero yes we assume /myserivce only serve those bundled files (through nginx static file serving), i.e., mostly frontend things, and API calls to backend will go through other paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
output: {
    publicPath: "/myservice",
},
```

The `publicPath` component will be inserted into the `href` before the `css` or `js` uri path component.

Documentation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/